# Error installing zlib1g-dev in ubuntu 16.04 desktop

Tags: 16.04, apt, lubuntu, dependencies, ffmpeg

I am trying to install ffmpeg in Ubuntu 16.04 and it has a dependency package zlib1g-dev. when running `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`. I am getting the below error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zlib1g-dev : Depends: zlib1g (= 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I read somewhere it might be due to a issue in `sources.list`. I've checked `sources.list` file it seems to be fine and verified with this link ( https://gist.github.com/rohitrawat/60a04e6ebe4a9ec1203eac3a11d4afc1 ) and `sudo apt-get update` doesn't shows any error as well. Can you please suggest. Thanks!!!

EDIT 1: I've also followed solution on this link ( [E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) ) and executed 
sudo apt-mark showhold
but it didn't print anything. So couldn't unmark anything
also tried the solution with aptitude and the log by running
sudo aptitude install zlib1g-dev was:

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  zlib1g-dev{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
Need to get 168 kB of archives. After unpacking 426 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zlib1g-dev : Depends: zlib1g (= 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

```
 Keep the following packages at their current version:
```

1)     zlib1g-dev [Not Installed]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

Comment: I tried after installing aptitude it suggested the solution but nothing happened and also tried apt-mark showhold but nothing happened. Still at square one

Answer (score 1):

Answer for this is given by SeinopSys in [Error installing zlib1g-dev](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993609/error-installing-zlib1g-dev) 
you need to take note of the required package version (in your case `= 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4`), then run the command below to downgrade to that version:

```
$ sudo apt install zlib1g=1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4
```

Then you can try re-installing.